# Variant-aware build configuration not working for Android Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am working on a huge Android library project which will produce different build variants, e.g. **debug** and **release** version of the library. This library itself also need some dependencies and I need to configure its dependencies to be **debug and release respectively**. I use the **variant-aware** dependency management of Android Gradle Plugin 3.0+ and this works well for the library build. Below is how I configure my project:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    releaseImplementation files('libs/release/lib_x_release.jar')
    releaseImplementation files('libs/release/lib_y_release.jar')
    debugImplementation files('libs/debug/lib_x_debug.jar')
    debugImplementation files('libs/debug/lib_y_debug.jar')
    ...
}
```

Specifically, when I run command

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

The variant-aware dependency management will correctly help me pick up all  **debug version** of dependencies.

when I run command

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The variant-aware dependency management will correctly help me pick up all **release version** of dependencies.

I have a gradle "**property**" to dynamically set my `testBuildType` so that I can run **release version** of Android Instrumentation Test. See below:

```
android {   
    ...

    if (project.hasProperty('testInstrumentedRelease')) {
        testBuildType 'release'
    } else {
        testBuildType 'debug'
    }
    ...
}
```

**However**, this does not work for my **release version** of Android Instrumentation Test, when I run below command

```
./gradlew connectedCheck -PtestInstrumentedRelease
```

The classes of both `lib_x_release` and `lib_y_release` are not picked up properly and will output below errors:

> error: package com.xxx does not exist

the package `com.xxx` are from `lib_x_release` and `lib_y_release`.

So, now my question is has someone else ever encountered this before?

The variant-aware configuration, i.e. `releaseImplementation` and `debugImplementation`, should also work for **Android Instrumentation Test**, right?

How do you solve this problem?

I have logged a bug to Google here: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112277358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `releaseImplementation` and `debugImplementation`, try below configuration, it will always pickup your correct dependencies even for your **Android Instrumentation Test**.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    if (project.hasProperty('testInstrumentedRelease')) {
        implementation files('libs/release/lib_x_release.jar')
        implementation files('libs/release/lib_y_release.jar')    
    } else {
        implementation files('libs/debug/lib_x_debug.jar')
        implementation files('libs/debug/lib_y_debug.jar')
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a kind of workaround.  But why don't `releaseImplementation` and `debugImplementation` not work for androidTest? Is it a bug of Android Gradle Plugin?